# Counting values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a possible duplicate entry. Unfortunalty i can't figure this out from the other entries on Stackoverflow. So please help, if you can :)

I am playing with a mini statistics script in php, to show some basic statistics.

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
$found_data = 
array( 
    array('2011-11-02' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-02' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-04' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-15' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-18' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-21' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-23' => 'mobile'),
    array('2011-11-28' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-30' => 'mobile')
);
```

Now i want to represent this data like this:

```
2011-11-01: 0 from mobile and 0 from desktop
2011-11-02: 2 from mobile and 0 from desktop
...
2011-11-30: 1 from mobile and 0 from desktop
```

I'm pretty sure you got the idea.

I have tried the following in a lot of variations, but nothing works:

```
echo count(array_keys($found_data['2011-11-02'], "mobile"));
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it in a different wy, than the above suggested.

If any one should be interested, this is the answer:

```
$found_data = 
array( 
    array('2011-11-02' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-02' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-04' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-08' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-15' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-18' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-21' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-23' => 'Mobile'),
    array('2011-11-28' => 'Desktop'),
    array('2011-11-30' => 'Mobile')
);



foreach($found_data as $single_data)
{
    foreach($single_data as $data => $key)
    {   
        $array_combined[$data]['Mobile'] = array();
        $array_combined[$data]['Tablet'] = array();
        $array_combined[$data]['Desktop'] = array();                
    }
}


foreach($found_data as $single_data)
{
    foreach($single_data as $data => $key)
    {
        if($key=='Desktop')
            array_push($array_combined[$data]['Desktop'], $key);
        else if($key=='Tablet')
            array_push($array_combined[$data]['Tablet'], $key);
        else if($key=='Mobile')
            array_push($array_combined[$data]['Mobile'], $key); 

    }
}


$startdate = strtotime('2011-11-01 00:00:01');
$days = 30;

echo 'Total hits the last 30 days: '.count($found_data).'<br />';

echo 'Desktop hits the last 30 days<br />';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $startdate+$i*60*60*24);
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $date, array_key_exists($date, $array_combined) ? count($array_combined[$date]['Desktop']) : 0);
    echo '<br />';
}

echo 'Tablet hits the last 30 days<br />';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $startdate+$i*60*60*24);
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $date, array_key_exists($date, $array_combined) ? count($array_combined[$date]['Tablet']) : 0);
    echo '<br />';
}

echo 'Mobile hits the last 30 days<br />';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $startdate+$i*60*60*24);
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $date, array_key_exists($date, $array_combined) ? count($array_combined[$date]['Mobile']) : 0);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Propably not the best solution, but works as intented.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot index your $found_data like this: `$found_data['2011-11-02']` because you have no key named '2011-11-02' there. Your $found_data declaration is equivalent to:

```
$found_data = 
array( 
    0 => array('2011-11-02' => 'mobile'),
    1 => array('2011-11-02' => 'mobile'),
    2 => array('2011-11-04' => 'mobile'),
    ... // and so on
);
```

I know you're using multidimension to use the same key multiple times, but as the structure above shows, you can't simply use `array_keys`.

One way to get what you want is to:

1. Create a result variable, initialize as empty array
2. Get next item in $found_data
3. Get the `key` and `value` of the item
4. Check whether `key` exists in result, if yes, increment the respective `value`. Otherwise create a new array with `mobile` and `desktop` as keys, and use `value` to determine which one should be initialize with 1 (the other is then 0). Assign this array to result with key `key`

The expected result array structure is like this:

```
$result = array(
    '2011-11-02' => array(
        'mobile' => 2,
        'desktop' => 1,
    ),
    '2011-11-04' => array(
        'mobile' => 0,
        'desktop' => 1,
    ),
    '2011-11-05' => array(
        'mobile' => 2,
        'desktop' => 0,
    ),
);
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean.. Can you give me an example to point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a great idea! I will test later today and write after, +1 for now :)